# Did Captain Barbossa continue his career as a privateer in the fifth film?

Tags: character, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

[image]

In the fourth film, Captain Barbossa became a privateer by taking the royal pardon from King George. In the fifth film, he wears a British culture wig. His hat and clothes also belong to the British. And I don't think Great Britain will allow him to freely pirate the seas after all that happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, he's no longer a privateer, but a powerful and wealthy pirate controlling the seven seas.

At one point towards the end of *On Stranger Tides Barbossa* declares,

> "**I care not for King George** or tavern yarns that give hope for a
> healed limb. But I'd give my left arm for a chance at Blackbeard."

and later after Blackbeard is defeated,

> "All hands! Ply to windward! Get cracking, ye bloomin' cockroaches!
> [laughs] **The Crown served me well. But now, by the Gods of sea and
> sky! Make way for Tortuga!**"

[Hector Barbossa](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Hector_Barbossa) returned to a life of piracy and at the beginning of *Dead Men Tell No Tales*, he's become *'the terror of seven sees'* by use of Blackbeard's former sword and Queen Anne's Revenge...

> He became the terror of the Seven Seas, pillaging the wealthy trade
> ships and filling the holds of the Queen Anne's Revenge with treasures
> beyond most men's wildest dreams. **With the power of the Sword of
> Triton, Barbossa finally fulfilled his old desire of living the life
> of a rich rogue. He surrounded himself with riches, dressing himself
> in finest uniforms he could steal, and even replaced his wooden peg
> leg with one made of gold. He successfully took over the pirate
> world, his name being whispered in fear across the Caribbean**, and when
> his Jolly Roger was spotted at sea, pirates and soldiers alike knew it
> was only a matter of time before they were conquered.

It also becomes clear that there aren't many real challenges left and that he almost seems bored with this life style and it's the challenge of Salazar and reveal of Carina that seems to give the character some real meaning to his life back.

Comment: I'm wondering, whether was Jack ever afraid of his old first mate..

Comment: A golden peg leg seems... impractical.

Comment: @Kakturus Aye, but it looked nice!

Comment: @Vishwa I think Jack's too perpetually drunk to be afraid of quite a lot of things he should be.

Comment: @Vishwa the first film proposed if he was brilliant or just crazy. Between the second and third films he kind of breaks down via death/davy jones locker, but then kind of bounces back in the fourth film, only to completely loose it and become super scared (compass = thing you fear most) in the fifth film. I'm not even convinced it was Salazar that he was scared of, but the implications of undoing curses, such as bringing Davy Jones back as hinted at in the post credit scene.

Comment: @DarthLocke I'll go for brilliant in a snap. IMO, he doesn't *fear* death nor Davy Jones. he hated being away from his beloved Sea, Pearl and adventure. I'm not sure he even afraid of Salazar. being crazy (not in a clinical term) may helped him do that. TL;DR - I dun think Jack was ever being afraid of anything other than being separated from the Sea and Pearl

Comment: @user25730 aren't them all?